# Python3 custom update functions for lists/dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm creating a terminal based game and after using an answer from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142950/check-and-update-dictionary-if-key-exists-doesnt-change-value), I realized I ran into another problem. I needed to figure out how to properly update stats on a character based on set class, and their solution worked. But now I need to figure out how to update it if it's not a number. So far I generated one for strings, but now I need one for a list of data.

For example, the `player` class so far consists of a base character with default stats and values.

```
class BaseCharacter:
    #define what to do when the object is created, or when you call player = BaseCharacter()
    def __init__(self):
        #generate all the stats. these are the default stats, not necessarily used by the final class when player starts to play.
        #round(random.randint(25,215) * 2.5) creates a random number between 25 and 215, multiplies it by 2.5, then roudns it to the nearest whole number
        self.gold = round(random.randint(25, 215) * 2.5)
        self.currentHealth = 100
        self.maxHealth = 100
        self.stamina = 10
        self.resil = 2
        self.armor = 20
        self.strength = 15
        self.agility = 10
        self.criticalChance = 25
        self.spellPower = 15
        self.speed = 5
        self.first_name = 'New'
        self.last_name = 'Player'
        self.desc = "Base Description"
        self.class_ = None
        self.equipment = [None] * 6
```

The update function that I used from my last question goes as follows:

```
#define the function to update stats when the class is set
def updateStats(self, attrs, factors):
    #try to do a function
    try:
        #iterate, or go through data
        for attr, fac in zip(attrs, factors):
            val = getattr(self, attr)
            setattr(self, attr, val * fac)
    #except an error with a value given or not existing values
    except:
            raise("Error updating stats.")
```

So when I create a `WarriorCharacter` based off of the `BaseCharacter`...

```
class WarriorCharacter(BaseCharacter):
    #define data when initialized, or the Object is created
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__()
        #update the class value since its a copy of BaseCharacter
        self.class_ = 'Warrior'
        #update the first name
        self.first_name = first_name
        #update the last name
        self.last_name = last_name
        #update description value
        self.desc = 'You were  born a protector. You grew up to bear a one-handed weapon and shield, born to prevent harm to others. A warrior is great with health, armor, and defense.'
        self.updateStats(['stamina', 'resil', 'armor', 'strength', 'speed'], [1.25, 1.25, 1.35, 0.75, 0.40])
```

... I can run `self.updateStats(['stamina', 'resil', 'armor', 'strength', 'speed'], [1.25, 1.25, 1.35, 0.75, 0.40])` in the Warrior class to properly update the new stats of the created player.

**However** I had to slightly revise the `updateStats` function for the `shops` class, because it uses mostly strings instead of numbers, by updating the for loop.

```
for attr, fac in zip(attrs, factors):
                setattr(self, attr, fac)
```

With the shop class...

```
class BaseShop:

    def __init__(self):
        #generate shop information
        self.name = "Base Shop"
        self.gold = round(random.randint(325, 615) * 2)
        self.desc = "Base Description"
        self.stock = [None] * random.randint(3, 8)
        self.vendor = "Base Vendor"
        #set responses
        #. . .
```

... This allows me to call `shop.updateShopInfo(["vendor"], ["Test Vendor"])` to change the shops vendor name from `'Base Vendor'` to `'Test Vendor'`

## The Problem

Now I don't know how to revise this function for an array/list data type. As you saw in the example I had a few variables such as `self.equipment = [None] * 6` and `self.stock = [None] * random.randint(3, 8)`. I want to be able to `update` these stats with items from the `item` class which is going to built like so:

```
class BaseItem:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Base Item Name"
        self.desc = "Base Item Description"
        self.itemType = None
        self.itemSize = None
        self.stats = {
            'Strength': 0,
            'Agility': 0,
            'Critical Chance': 0,
            'Spell Power': 0,
            'Speed': 0,
            'Health': 0,
            'Stamina': 0,
            'Armor': 0,
            'Resilience': 0
        }
        self.slot = None
    #my attempt at it so far
    def updateItemStats(self, attrs, factors):
        try:
            #iterate, or go through data
            for attr, fac in zip(attrs, factors):
                val = getattr(self, attr)
                setattr(self, attr, val + fac)
        #except an error with a value given or not existing values
        except:
            raise("Error updating stats.")

class OneHandedSword(BaseItem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.itemType = "Sword"
        self.itemSize = "One Hand"
        self.name = "Jade Serpentblade"
        self.desc = "Sharp cutlass."
        self.slot = "Weapon"
        #something like this? would update the stats value of the new item to have +5 strength and +2 stamina
        self.update([self.stats["strength"], self.stats["stamina"]], [5, 2])
```

## What I tried

The update function throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Python/game_Test/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    item2 = OneHandedSword()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Python/game_Test/assets/items.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.updateItemStats([self.stats["Strength"], self.stats["Stamina"]], [5, 2]) 
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Python/game_Test/assets/items.py", line 33, in updateItemStats
    raise("Error updating stats.")
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

When I take out the `try/except`, it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Python/game_Test/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    item2 = OneHandedSword()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Python/game_Test/assets/items.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.updateItemStats([self.stats["Strength"], self.stats["Stamina"]], [5, 2]) 
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Python/game_Test/assets/items.py", line 28, in updateItemStats
    val = getattr(self, attr)
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

I then tried editing `val = getattr(self, attr)` to `val = gettattr(self, self.stats[attr]` it then returns `KeyError: 0`

## What I need

So I essentially need **two** update functions, one for updating the `item.stats` dictionary, and one for updating the `stock` and `equipment` lists with `item` objects. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `self.update([self.stats["strength"], self.stats["stamina"]], [5, 2])` should be `self.update(['strength','stamina'],[5,2])`. Also, what are you trying to do with `raise("Error updating stats.")`? Why are you even trying to catch an error here? You should never be using bare-except clauses anyway.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga its mostly a filler as i develop the program., for the error part. Ill try your solution for the update when i get the chance.

Comment: And actually, you want to be `setattr(self.stats, <whatever>)` I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga After some tinkering and using your suggestions, I got it  to work. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.